# Are C pointers causing a triple fault for my home-brew kernels VGA section?

Tags: c, pointers, operating-system, kernel

I'm trying to get a simple Hello World! kernel to boot. Whenever I turn on my virtual machine I see GRUB load, select my OS, then get a random character on the screen, and crash with a triple fault. I believe the problem lies in my VGA section. I suspect that the issue lies somewhere with my use of C pointers. Neither C, nor pointers, are a strong suit. Specifically, I suspect the put_char() function to be involved. There were some compiler issues involving pointers. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks for helping!

Here's the code for my VGA section:

```
/*
    This file will handle dealing with VGA stuff so I can print to the screen.
*/

#include <system.h>

/* this pointer will be set to the VGA access memory address */
unsigned short *text_ptr;
int attrib = 0x0F; // foreground and background color gets set in here.
int csr_x = 0; // cursor x position
int csr_y = 0; // cursor y position
int screen_width = 80; // width of the screen in columns
int screen_height = 25; // height of the screen in rows

void vga_initialize()
{
    // set the text pointer to the proper location in memory
    text_ptr = (unsigned short *) 0x0B8000;
    clear_screen();
}

void set_text_color(unsigned char foreground_color, unsigned char background_color)
{
    attrib = (background_color << 4) | (foreground_color & 0x0F);
}

void put_str(char *text)
{
    // figure out the length of the string we'll be printing
    char *my_text = text;    // make a local copy of the pointer so the orinal's not overwritten.
    int str_length;
    for (str_length = 0; *my_text != '\0'; my_text++)    // set the string lenght to 0; if the character at the pointer isn't zero; increment the pointer
    {
        str_length++;    // increment the count
    }
    // for each character in the string
    for (int i = 0; i < str_length; i++)
    {
        put_char(my_text[i]); // put the character on the screen
    }
}

void put_char(char c)
{
    unsigned short *index_ptr;
    unsigned int my_attrib = attrib << 8;

    if (c == 0x08) // backspace
    {
        if (csr_x != 0)
        {
            csr_x--;
        }
    }
    else if (c == 0x09) // tab
    {
        csr_x = (csr_x + 8) & ~(8 - 1); // increment x but only to a point that will make it divisible by 8 (i dunno, lawl)
    }
    else if (c == '\r') // carriage return, move cursor to beginning of row
    {
        csr_x = 0;
    }
    else if (c == '\n') // newline
    {
        csr_x = 0;
        csr_y++;
    }
    else if (c >= ' ') // any character greater than or equal to space is a printable character
    {
        // figure out where to put the character
        index_ptr = text_ptr + (csr_y * screen_width + csr_x);
        // put the character and it's attribute into memory, which will put it on the screen when it refreshes.
        *index_ptr = c | my_attrib;
    }

    scroll();
    move_csr();
}



void scroll()
{
    unsigned short space_char = 0x20 | (attrib << 8);
    // used to calculate the offsets needed when moving data around in the vga buffer memory
    int temp_offset;
    // screen's full, we need to scroll
    if (csr_y >= screen_height)
    {
        // move everything up
        temp_offset = csr_y - screen_height + 1; // offset for calculating the addresses to use in the vga memory
        memcpy(text_ptr, text_ptr + temp_offset * screen_width, (screen_height - temp_offset) * screen_width * 2);
        // set the chunk of memory that occupies the last line of text to spaces
        memsetw(text_ptr + (screen_height - temp_offset) * screen_width, space_char, screen_width);
        // adjust the position of the cursor
        csr_y = screen_height - 1;
    }
}

void move_csr()
{
    unsigned char curr_pos = csr_y * screen_width + csr_x;
    outportb(0x3D4, 14);
    outportb(0x3D5, curr_pos >> 8);
    outportb(0x3D4, 15);
    outportb(0x3D5, curr_pos);
}

void clear_screen()
{
    unsigned short space_char;

    // i need to generate the ascii code? that represents a space of the proper background color
    space_char = 0x20 | (attrib << 8);

    // write spaces to the entire screen
    for (int i = 0; i < screen_height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < screen_width; j++)
        {
            memsetw(text_ptr + i * screen_width, space_char, 1);
        }
    }

    // reset the cursors x and y position
    csr_x = 0;
    csr_y = 0;
    move_csr(); // and reset the cursor in the hardware
}
```

I've been following along with various tutorials in an attempt to make my own operating system. So far I've been having a pretty good time with the GNU tool chain described [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones). I'm using the GNU Assembler with the tool chain because I followed the directions, and didn't think about building NASM into it. I'd rather learn another flavor of Assembly than redo the tool chain. :-P I've been modeling my attempts on [Bran's Kernel Development tutorial.](http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/title.htm) I'm trying to keep the C code and GAS code in separate files because I don't like how the tutorials have all of the Assembly bunched into the boot loader. I'm making this on a Windows 7 machine, but using Debian for my coding. I have Oracle VirtualBox installed on Windows, and use it to emulate Debian. I then have Debian set up with my development tools, and use the text editor to code.

Below is a link to all of the code I'm using, VirtualBox logs of the crash, a log file of the commands I'm using in the Debian terminal to build my code, the object files, binary files, and iso files I've made.

http://wikisend.com/download/243118/POS_C3.zip

If you'd like to see the error yourself then you should be able to mount pos.iso onto a virtual machine, and run it. It should crash as advertised. At this time I've made code for the boot loader, kernel main function, GDT, and VGA stuff. I have the memory and I/O port functions in their own C files, and the GAS for the GDT is in its own file as well.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but, you might consider using qemu or bochs. You can attach gdb to them and step through your kernel code. The print to screen portion of your kernel is going to be the simple part. It is going to get much more complex. Not having a debugger is almost not an option, unless you're Dutch.

Comment: I would like a debugger, but bochs doesn't seem to be an option for me. I'm not seeing a Windows installation option. To use bochs I'd need to emulate it in an emulator. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: I run qemu in qemu all the time. It is not going to cause an issue.

Comment: @Ian Laird: I've been looking into Bochs and Qemu recently. Have you found any good guides on making the disk images those programs need? I'm wanting to run an .iso image, and these programs are a bit more involved than VirtualBox.

Comment: Here is the method i use: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU Look at section "Mounting a partition inside a raw disk image"
A better option, IMHO, would be to use qemu and the just pass the kernel over the command line. It will emulate a multiboot complaint loader for you and you can step around the disk image all together. at least until you have a more fully developed kernel.

qemu-system-x86_64 -m [MEMORY] -kernel [KERNEL.BIN]

Comment: This is a resource for doing what you are trying to do:
http://wiki.osdev.org/How_Do_I_Use_A_Debugger_With_My_OS

Comment: I searched and wasn't able to find a way to run Qemu in Windows, so I'm having to do them in Debian. >.< I'm following along with the instructions from the OSDev Wiki, and got Qemu w/ ddd working. I can use ddd to send a continue command to Qemu, but am not seeing much of anything in ddd. I compiled everything with the gcc -g option, and got a .bin then used grub-mkrescue to make a bootable .iso. I take it I now need to get a symbol table set up for ddd to use w/ gdb? That's where I'm getting lost. The instructions on OSDev are going over objcopy with a .elf file. Can i do that on a .bin?

Comment: No, you will need to compile to an elf then use objcopy to create the bin. At that point, if you have included debugging information (-ggdb), then you can load symbols from the elf file.

Comment: So add the -f elf tag to my gcc calls in the make file? Do I put that on every file as it's compiling, or just on the linker stage? Also, when compiling for debug with gcc should I use just the -g flag, or the -ggdb you're recommending? What's the difference?

Comment: Since i don't know the details of your environment, i cannot completely answer that question. Generically i would say, you only need the format on the call to the linker.  Here is an OS i started a few months ago. It is far from done but it might help you line up your build environment. https://github.com/en0/rpos

Comment: I'm using the tool chain described in the OSDev Bare Bones article, and following Bran's Kernel Development tutorial. Doing it in the linker makes sense, considering that's where all the object files are combined. I should just have to change a couple of flags in my makefile. Trying to debug interrupts now. Thanks for the github link. I'll be looking that over.

Comment: @Ian Laird Looks like I'm making some progress. I have Qemu and DDD running, and appear to have control of things with DDD. I can use info registers to see values changing, and when I click Stepi it tells me the names of the functions my kernel uses, and in order. What I'm not seeing is any of my code. What's up with that? Do I need to specify my source files?

Comment: I am not very familiar DDD.  But i think it uses GDB backend.  If it does then all you should need to do is run the command, "symbol-file [PATH]" where path is your kernel in elf format. If that works, the code source should be refrenced in the symbol table and auto load. Outside of that i would recommend reading up on your debugger to understand it.http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/manual/html_mono/ddd.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60756/discussion-between-ian-laird-and-patrick-sanford).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues I see:

1) Your `put_str()` function accesses invalid memory beyond the end of the `text` string, which is undefined behavior:

```
void put_str(char *text)
{
    char *my_text = text; // (1)
    int str_length;
    for (str_length = 0; *my_text != '\0'; my_text++) // (2)
    {
        str_length++;    // increment the count
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str_length; i++)
    {
        put_char(my_text[i]); // (3)
    }
}
```

In this case, you assign `my_text` to the start of the string at (1) and then advance it to the end of the string at (2).  You then proceed to index into it from the end of the string at (3), which reads memory out of bounds.  You probably meant to write `text[i]` instead of `my_text[i]` at (3), or maybe you forgot to reset `my_text = text;` before that loop (either would produce equivalent results).  You could also replace the entire first loop with a call to `strlen()`, but instead of that there's a much simpler solution:

```
void put_str(char *text)
{
    while (*text != 0)
    {
        put_char(*text);
        text++;
    }
}
```

This walks through the string looking for the NUL terminator and outputs each character as it goes.  No need to count the string length first and then reiterate through the string again.

2) This call to `memcpy()` inside the `scroll()` function has undefined behavior because the source and destination memory ranges can overlap:

```
memcpy(text_ptr, text_ptr + temp_offset * screen_width, (screen_height - temp_offset) * screen_width * 2);
```

This likely wouldn't cause the triple fault exceptions you were seeing, but it can cause data to be copied incorrectly in strange ways, depending on how `memcpy()` is implemented in your standard library.  But since it's undefined behavior, you have to be prepared for anything, including demons flying out of your nose.

The simple and easy solution is to replace it with a call to [`memmove()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) instead, which has defined behavior even when the source and destination memory ranges overlap:

```
memmove(text_ptr, text_ptr + temp_offset * screen_width, (screen_height - temp_offset) * screen_width * 2);
```

Comment: I made the changes to put_str() that you recommended, and still get the same issue. You're probably correct in suspecting my use of memcpy(). I'm actually not using the standard c library on this build. I have memcpy() defined in a file which #include my system.h file.

    void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, int count)
    {
        int i; // a loop control variable
        const char *source_ptr = (const char *) src;
        char *dest_ptr = (char *) dest;
        for (i = count; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            *dest_ptr++ = *source_ptr++;
        }
        return dest;
    }

Comment: @PatrickSanford: Well there's another problem, your `memcpy()` implementation is broken.  How many bytes are copied when `count` is 1?  It *should* be 1, but you actually copy 2 bytes due to an off-by-one error.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help. I'll look into fixing that when I have time later today. I also asked my operating systems teacher about it, and he seemed to think there may be an issue with an interrupt or how GRUB is initializing things. Disabling interrupts to test if that's causing it will be rather simple. Do you know how to check the GRUB configuration options? I was unaware that GRUB could initialize the video in different ways. What's the default mode that it initializes in?

Comment: PS: I am taking an OS class this semester, but this project is not a part of it. The class only covers OS theory. I'm attempting to apply the theory for my own enjoyment.

Comment: OK, I made the changes you recommended, and think I've figured out what's casing the triple fault. It has to do with interrupts, as my teacher suggested. When I comment out the asm volatile ("sti"); line in my kernel_main() function the triple fault doesn't occur, but nothing gets printed either. Do I need to get the IDT and interrupt service routines going before I can use VGA?

Comment: After some extensive code review, and debugging, I just got it working. Had a good boot, and Hello World! event. It's a good feeling. :-D Thank you very much for your help. You helped clear up several things that were very frustrating.